# Add parameters to URL using select

Tags: html, forms, url, select, parameters

I know next to 0 when it comes to code, but it is an area I like more and more. 
Here is the deal, Im trying to make a search form that searches an external website. I'm using dropdowns and the url then gets populated based on the choices. Simple right?

But now I have a select with value in the followin format:

```
<option value="abc-ut-45">Lorem</option>
```

And it should populate the url with `pp=abc&rr=ut&ff=45`

I stuck in a wall, because for single parameters its eaasy.
For example:
On one of the dropdowns I have this:

```
<select name="o">
            <option value="">Choose one</option>
            <option value="1">Buy</option>
            <option value="2">Trade</option>
        </select>
```

And then the url gets the `o= 1 or 2` based on the choise.

But this dropdown that Im struggling with has 3 different values that I need to populate the url with different parameters, so I don't know what to add in the `<select name="">`

Comment: Your `<form>` should submit to a page on **your own website**, which would then generate (and check) the external request to your target website. Form submission to external websites are suspicious and are highly likely to be blocked. The User of your form can also easily manipulate the data and cause havok (`;-)`)

Comment: `<form>` --> `submit` --> `take variables; build URL` --> `forward browser to that URL`

Comment: Three separate <select> groups.  In your example, name="pp" first select,name="rr" for second select, name="ff" for third select.  Your from method="get" to add form variables to the URL instead of as POST data.